# Stopwatch getting static value from runnable, editing variable inside runnable

Tags: multithreading, handler, runnable, stopwatch

I'm going to create stopwatch and i got some trouble. My code looks that:

**1 For start button:**

```
    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
               // some code
      mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
      mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1);
      start.setText("Lap");
     }});
```

**2 For runnable:**

> public Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {

```
     public void run() {
          EditText licznik = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          // some code
          licznik.setText(time+"");
mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);

      }
   };
```

My stopwatch works great for: Start, Stop.

But I can't create inside reset button's onclicklistener action: `licznik.setText("");`
because licznik is initiated inside mUpdateTimeTask, I also can't move licznik outside mUpdateTimeTask because it's not working then.

Additionally as you noticed my start button after click will change to lap and lap should get actually time from runnable. I have no idea how do it because runnable is dynamic.

Have anyone some solution?

Comment: why can't you make `mUpdateTimeTask` non-anonymous implementation of `Runnable` with constructor which accepts `licznik` as parameter? This way you will be able to share `licznik` between listener and `mUpdateTimeTask`...

Comment: you mean create class mUpdateTimeTask implements Runnable ? if yes, I tried do that but then I can't use mHandler, if not, please explain me how to do that

Comment: Can you please show code where you try to create `mUpdateTimeTask implements Runnable` and how it fails for your task?

Comment: ye sure I tried do something like that:
public class mUpdateTimeTask implements Runnable{
Runnable rr = new Runnable(
public void run(){
// some my staff
}
);
}
After that when when I tried use handler:
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask.this.rr, 1); I got error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this would help, but you can create `Runnable` in following way:

```
class UpdateTimeTask implements Runnable {
    private final EditText whatever;

    UpdateTimeTask(EditText whatever) {
        this.whatever = whatever;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // act upon whatever
    }
}
```